# findstr exit codes/errorlevel

Tags: cmd, exit-code, findstr, errorlevel

I have a program that is using `findstr`, and when the string is found the `errorlevel` returns `0` and when the string is not found the `errorlevel` returns `1`. Alright, that's fine I can deal with that.

Where the issue lies is I cannot find any official documentation on what each `errorlevel` means for `findstr`. I need to know if anything else for `findstr` could ever return an `errorlevel` of `1`, or if it only returns `1` when the string is not found.

Links to 'official' documentation are preferred, if there are any, but any input would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html says:

```
FINDSTR will set %ERRORLEVEL% as follows:

0 (False) a match is found in at least one line of at least one file.
1 (True) if a match is not found in any line of any file, (or if the file is not found at all).
2 Wrong syntax 
An invalid switch will only print an error message in error stream.
```

Answer (score 1):

It is documented in the Dos 6.22 Help for FIND command.

```
│FIND exit codes
│
│The following list shows each exit code and a brief description of its
│meaning:
│
│0
│    The search was completed successfully and at least one match was found.
│
│1
│    The search was completed successfully, but no matches were found.
│
│2
│    The search was not completed successfully. In this case, an error
│    occurred during the search, and FIND cannot report whether any matches
│    were found.
│
│You can use the ERRORLEVEL parameter on the <If> command line in a batch
│program to process exit codes returned by FIND.
```

Comment: Does this also apply to `findstr'?

Comment: Yes. I searched for a more recent reference for 12 years. I have Dos 6.22 and OS/2 Warp 4 (it says _It returns 0 for normal completion_).